# Limiting the scope of a temporary variable

Tags: c++, scope, stack

Without resorting to the heap, I would like a temporary variable to pass out of scope, freeing its storage on the stack.  However, I can think of no neat way to achieve the desired effect in a case like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    const int numerator {14}, denominator {3};

    // ...

    // The desired scope begins here.
    const std::div_t quotient_and_remainder {std::div(numerator, denominator)};
    const int x_lo {
        quotient_and_remainder.quot
    };
    const int x_hi {
        quotient_and_remainder.quot + (quotient_and_remainder.rem ? 1 : 0)
    };
    // The desired scope ends here.
    // The quotient_and_remainder should pass out of scope.

    // ...

    std::cout
        << "The quotient " << numerator << "/" << denominator
        << " is at least " << x_lo
        << " and is not more than " << x_hi << "." << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

At the low machine level, one desires the following.

1. Storage is first reserved on the stack for `x_lo` and `x_hi`.
2. The `quotient_and_remainder` is then pushed temporarily onto the stack.
3. The `quotient_and_remainder` is used to calculate values which are written into `x_lo` and `x_hi`.
4. Having done its duty, the `quotient_and_remainder` is **popped off the stack.**

At the high programming level, one desires the following.

5. The compiler enforces that `x_lo` and `x_hi` remain constant.
6. The name `quotient_and_remainder` does not clutter the function's entire local namespace.

At both levels, one would like to avoid wasting memory and runtime.  (To waste compilation time is okay.)

In my actual program—which is too long to post here—the values of `numerator` and `denominator` are unknown at compile time, so `constexpr` cannot be used.

Ordinarily, I can think of various sound ways to achieve such effects using, for example, extra braces or maybe an anonymous lambda; but this time, I'm stumped.

(One should prefer to solve the problem without anti-idiomatic shenanigans like `const_cast`.  However, if shenanigans were confined to a small part of the program to avert maintainabilty problems, then shenanigans might be acceptable if there existed no better choice.)

Comment: "popped off the stack". Any decent compiler will not have these variables on the stack in the first place. What you afk for is actually suboptimal. And even if you have variable scopes that overlap and not enough registers, modern compilers can use Static Single Assignment (SSA) to rewrite your code. This will split `quotient_and_remainder` into two distinct variables with non-overlapping scopes. In SSA, _all_ variables are treated as const; re-assignment is solved by introducing new variables (hence the name Single Assignment)

Comment: I don't think what you desire actually saves any space or runs faster. The call stack is pre-allocated. No?

Comment: Whats wrong with creating block around that area?

Comment: @Lingxi: There's no hard requirement for that in C++. Optimizing compilers may for instance decide that a code block throwing an exception is unlikely, and postpone allocation until the throw actually happens. You wouldn't be able to tell: if the memory was needed, it was allocated, and if it wasn't, you can't tell it was not allocated.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry, but I don't quite get it. I understand that this may be implementation detail, not something specified by the std. Still, I think call stack size is set to a fixed value at program building time ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-170)). When a new thread starts, the call stack space is pre-allocated and cannot grow. If more space is needed, you have a stack overflow. This is not always the case?

Comment: @Slava That is why sample code was posted. If one compiles the sample code, the compiler tells why one cannot create a block around that area. The problem is that the temporary variable is pushed onto the stack **before memory is reserved** for the persistent variables. One can fight this effect with placement-new and other drastic means, but the question seeks a more idiomatic way to manage the stack properly. (One reader has pointed out that, after optimization, the stack is not actually used, which is probably true for my toy example but is beside the point.)

Comment: @Lingxi: It's indeed not that simple. The address space is typically reserved, but you don't need actual physical RAM yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, you can use a function and a structured binding declaration:

```
auto x_lo_x_hi = [](int numerator, int denominator) {
    std::div_t quotient_and_remainder {std::div(numerator, denominator)};
    return std::pair{
        quotient_and_remainder.quot,
        quotient_and_remainder.quot + (quotient_and_remainder.rem ? 1 : 0)
    };
};
const auto [x_lo, x_hi] = x_lo_x_hi(numerator, denominator);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8s5KdWqjK)

`x_lo_x_hi` doesn't have to be a local lambda. It could be some function declared elsewhere or it could even be an IIFE (an anonymous lambda that you call immediately on the same line).

That said, this only serves to remove the name `quotient_and_remainder` from the local scope. Like MSalters said in a comment, any decent compiler will optimize that variable away in your original code. And even if it didn't, removing one variable from the stack will not improve the runtime, and if you have stack memory problems, the actual issue is somewhere else.

Comment: This solution can be even smaller by removing x_lo_x_hi and adding an IIFE block `const auto [x_lo, x_hi] = ([]{ ... return std::pair<int, int>{x_lo, x_hi}})();`, but I understand you may have deliberately decided to write it this way to be more explicit.